# Uber Sdk (0.5.4) Booking giving error : Error : { message :Requires at least one scope. Available scopes , code:unauthorized }

Tags: uber-api

**Here is My Code :**

```
configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
        .setClientId(HostUrl.LIVE_CLIENT_ID)
        .setRedirectUri(HostUrl.Redirect_Uri)
        .setServerToken(HostUrl.Uber_server_token)
        .setClientSecret("xxxxx")
        .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.PRODUCTION)
        .setEndpointRegion(SessionConfiguration.EndpointRegion.WORLD)
        .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.PLACES))
        .build();
```

UberSdk.initialize(configuration);

```
accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(LoginNetworks.this);
mUberLoginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager,
        new SampleLoginCallback(),
        configuration,
        CUSTOM_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE);
```

mUberLoginManager.loginForImplicitGrant(LoginNetworks.this);

**Return Error**
{ message :Requires at least one scope. Available scopes , code:unauthorized }

when I update my Scope Like

```
.setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.REQUEST))
```

**OR**

```
.setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.REQUEST_RECEIPT))
```

**Error** 
login Error (UNKNOWN)

Comment: Where do you make your API call? If you want to book a ride,  like your title suggests, you'd need the [`request` scope](https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/uber/sdk/core/auth/Scope.java#L75).

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you are trying to make API calls to endpoints that require other scopes than the PROFILE and PLACES. Please share your source code for the calls to understand which endpoints you want to make requests to. Also, please check out the [Scopes](https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/scopes) guide for more information on scopes.

Comment: setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.PLACES))

Comment: when I add scopes like this

Comment: I am requesting for following Location :
lattitude : 17.415234
Longitude : 78.449058

when set scope like this :  
 setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE,Scope.PLACES,Scope.REQUEST_RECEIPT))
 
it's showing Login Error (UNKNOWN)

Comment: mUberLoginManager.loginforimplicitgrant(LoginNetworks.this);

Comment: when i login with mothod  :
               mUberLoginManager.login(LoginNetworks.this
 it's deep link to uber App .

Comment: Here is my code :
configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId(HostUrl.LIVE_CLIENT_ID)
                .setRedirectUri(HostUrl.Redirect_Uri)
                .setServerToken(HostUrl.Uber_server_token)
                .setClientSecret(HostUrl.Uber_client_secret)
                .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.PRODUCTION)              .setEndpointRegion(SessionConfiguration.EndpointRegion.WORLD)
                .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PLACES, Scope.PROFILE))
                .build();
        UberSdk.initialize(configuration);

Comment: accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(LoginNetworks.this);
        mUberLoginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager,
                new SampleLoginCallback(),
                configuration,
                CUSTOM_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE);

        mUberLoginManager.loginforimplicitgrant(LoginNetworks.this);

Comment: Please simply update your initial question instead of commenting on the answer. Most important is the block where you make the actual call. Didn't see that in your comments yet. Thanks.